# Problem with assigning characters from a std::string to a std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, string, ascii, stdvector

## **Problem**

I tried to assign every letter of a `std::string` to a `std::vector<std::string>`. I didn't use `std::vector<char>`, because these characters will be mixed, e.g. 3 -> 30. Unfortunately, instead of letters in the `std::vector` there are ASCII codes. Interestingly, when I tried to do this with old C-style arrays, the conversion went through without a problem and I had strings in the `std::string` array.

## **Code**

```cpp
template <typename numTyp>
void numberAsRoman<numTyp>::convert()
{
    numberAsArray = std::to_string(number); // numberAsArray is (int) member of class 
                                            // I convert it to std::string.

    std::vector<std::string> vecOfNum;               // Make vector
    for(int i = 0; i < numberAsArray.length(); i++)  // Loop to assign
    {                                                              
        vecOfNum.push_back(std::to_string(numberAsArray.at(i))); // I assign every letter 
        std::cout << vecOfNum.at(i) << "  ";                     // to vector and print it. 
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n\n"; 
}
```

## **What I see upon execution**

The `vector` is printing `51` and `50. I checked it, and it agrees with the ASCII codes:

```
51 - 3
50 - 2
```

Comment: *because these characters will be mixed, e.g. 3 -> 30* Could you explain it in more detail? Also be kind to post a [mcve], don't make other to extend the code and perhaps eliminate the issue.

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] with some hardcoded data and your expected and actual output from that data.

Comment: I intend to change them in the future. E.g. 3 I will change to 30 because I will add zero. From char (3) after adding + 0 it will make pages (30)

Comment: So, the minimal code and the clear question might look like `std::string s = std::to_string('2');`, why do I get `s` equal to "50"?

Comment: @273K Because `to_string()` only accepts integer types and floating types, not characters. But characters are numeric types that are implicitly convertible to integers. So `std::to_string('2')` is effectively `std::to_string((int)'2')` ie `std::to_string(50)` (if your compiler uses ASCII for its charset, which it should in this case).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why do you answer me? I have just offered improvement for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
vecOfNum.emplace_back(1, numberAsArray.at(i)));
```

The `std::string std::to_string(char c)` overload does not exist. `std::string to_string(int value);` is used like

```
int value = numberAsArray.at(i);  // c promotes to int getting ascii code of the containing character
vecOfNum.push_back(std::to_string(value));
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau Just used a wrong word

Comment: this answer would be much better if you had explained why the original code doesn't work, and why using `emplace_back()` does work.

Comment: @Remy You have voted down just because you don't like the accepted answer? You first have clinged to the word, now you just don't like my answer.

Comment: I downvoted because of the reasons I mentioned in my previous comment. In its current form, this answer is not very useful to future readers. It needs more substance behind it, IMHO. Sash's answer was better, but he deleted it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau **would be much better if you had explained why the original code doesn't work** I explained it! Read it carefully.